# MySQL has over 95,000 connections but processlist is empty?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connection, ip-conntrack

I have a server that is running mysql and it's using a lot of memory. I run:

```
mysql > show status like '%onn%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| Aborted_connects         | 4     |
| Connections              | 98609 |
| Max_used_connections     | 20    | 
| Ssl_client_connects      | 0     |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates | 0     |
| Ssl_finished_connects    | 0     |
| Threads_connected        | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

But then if I run 'show processlist' as the root user I don't see anything. I've tried google for this but It always comes up with stuff related to connection errors. Could someone please just explain why I can't see the connections and how to actually go in and see them?

Comment: Connections is total number of connections since the server started, not the current number of connections.

Comment: Well that explains one thing, but it still stands that the server is using huge amounts of RAM with no appearance of anything happening? I have to manually reboot the MySQL server to clear it all our but I don't think that's a very good way of solving the problem.

Comment: This doesn't help you, but my MySQL does the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178736/mysql-maximum-memory-usage and http://serverfault.com/questions/415530/how-do-i-assign-a-memory-limit-for-mysql may or may not also help. Once MySQL requests memory, it never gives it back (many Unix apps are like that), so your max memory usage = your current memory usage.

Comment: Awesome those links are very informative! Thankyou!

Comment: MySQL keeps lots of stuff, like database indexes, cached in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The `connection` parameter is a bit of a misnomer. It indicates the number of connections that have been made to the server *since the server started*. The one you might be interested in is `Threads connected`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ip_conntrack netfilter` module, Then you can manipulate maximum connections.
You have to change value of `net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max` via `sysctl`